# ufw rate limiting ansible on ubuntu 22

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, ufw

this was all done on ubuntu 22.

```
$ ufw version
ufw 0.36.1
Copyright 2008-2021 Canonical Ltd.

$ cat /etc/os-release | grep VERSION
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
```

Trying to connect to an ubuntu server from a github runner running `ansible`, I found that `ansible` was getting blocked by `UFW` and subsequently received connection time outs.

The `UFW` logs showed `[UFW LIMIT BLOCK]` so I knew it was rate limiting.  The strange thing is that I can manually connect using `SSH` from the github runner just fine, however I know `ansible` likes to open and close a lot of connections so it was probably triggering the rate limit.

To resolve, the `seconds` and `hit_count` for the `SSH` rule in `UFW` needs to be changed from the default of `seconds: 30 hit_count: 3` to something less aggressive.  Unfortunately the only way I found to do this was to modify the `UFW` source (thanks to https://jb.prose.sh/ufw-limit):
`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/ufw/backend_iptables.py`

adjusted the section:

```
# adjust for limit
  pat_limit = re.compile(r' -j LIMIT')
    for i, s in enumerate(snippets):
      if pat_limit.search(s):
        tmp1 = pat_limit.sub(' -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent --set', \                                               
                             s)
        tmp2 = pat_limit.sub(' -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m recent' + \
                             ' --update --seconds 30 --hitcount 3' + \
                             ' -j ' + prefix + '-user-limit', s)
        tmp3 = pat_limit.sub(' -j ' + prefix + '-user-limit-accept', s)
        snippets[i] = tmp3
        snippets.insert(i, tmp2)
        snippets.insert(i, tmp1)

  return snippets
```

and changed to `--seconds 10 --hitcount 24`

Anything less than that and `ansible` was blocked again.

implemented with

```
~$ sudo ufw disable
~$ sudo ufw enable
```

`ufw reload` was not sufficient as it would not replace the existing rule, just add the new rule next to it, which makes perfect sense since i'm adjusting the codebase.

Is there a better way of doing this?  I cant find much information on overriding the hardcoded defaults in `UFW`, which I'd assume is done through custom rules, but again, no information.

I also saw that github publishes their action runners ip ranges (https://api.github.com/meta), but holy crap it's long and not something that looked easy to manage in UFW.